# Динамические props для компонентов в массиве

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Только осваиваю React и столкнулся с проблемой:

В основном компоненте App есть простой компонент Container, который принимает массив различных компонентов и рендерит их "в себя". Также App имеет state

```
{
    isAcive: true,
    content: [] // здесь будут компоненты, которые передаются Container'у
}
```

**код компонента Container:**

```
const Container = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="Container">
            {props.content} //props.content - массив различных компонентов
        </div>
    );
}
```

**примерно так к нему обращаюсь (в App):**

```
<Container key="Container" content={this.state.content} />
```

**this.state.content** выше - это массив различных компонентов и создается он циклом после приема некоторых данных с сервера и записывается через setState в состояние content компонента App. Выглядит этот массив так:

```
[
    <CompA key="a" isActive={this.state.isActive} title={serverResponse[0].title} />,
    <CompB key="b" isActive={this.state.isActive} title={serverResponse[1].title} />,
    <CompC key="c" isActive={this.state.isActive} title={serverResponse[2].title} />
];
```

Проблема в том, что компоненты в массиве выше обращаются к стэйту App, затем берут значение isActive и "формируются" единожды после чего записываются в состояние content компонента App. Это означает, что при изменении у App стэйта isActive эти компоненты ни как не отреагируют и не "переформируются" с новым isActive.

Вопрос: Как заставить пропсы компонентов CompA, CompB и CompC быть как бы динамическими и меняться в зависимости от стэйта в App или, что я делаю не так?;

Что пробовал (стыдно): Передать Conteiner'у isActive и перебрать arrayWithSomeComponents внутри Conteiner'а через map, переписывая props.isActive у объектов CompA, CompB и CompC, но реакт ругается.

Многословно, но, думаю, ясно объяснил суть проблемы. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: "это обязательное условие" - вот этим загнали себя в угол. Можно поинтересоваться причиной такого странного условия?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov хорошо. Я слишком все упростил для ясности (но это была плохая идея, видимо). Отредачил вопрос. Суть в том, что компоненты формируются единожды после ответа от сервера. Взгляни